How does KPSS test for stationarity if it is about trend stationarity vs unit roots?
ADF Test:

Null Hypothesis: The series has a unit root.
Alternate Hypothesis: The series has no unit root.

KPSS test:

Null Hypothesis: The process is trend stationary.
Alternate Hypothesis: The series has a unit root (series is not stationary).


It is always better to apply both the tests, so that it can be ensured
that the series is truly stationary.

Source:
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/stationarity_detrending_adf_kpss.html
What I don’t understand is if you’re using the KPSS test, why does failing to reject the null imply stationarity if the null is trend stationary?
